# Make a products only viewable to a specific user ID in meta_query pre_get_posts

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic, pre-get-posts

I need to show some products to specific users set in the product itself by an ACF field that stores the user ID.

I want to hide the product from the product category page / shop completely unless they have been assigned that product.

I've tried using `pre_get_posts` for this, but have had no luck.

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'custom_products_remove_product_from_shop');
function custom_products_remove_product_from_shop($query)
{
    if ($query->is_main_query() && is_product_category()) {
        $query->set('meta_query', [
            [
                'key' => 'custom_product_customer',
                'value' => '',
                'compare' => '!='
            ]
        ]);
    }

    return $query;
}
```

In my mind, that code should work perfectly as we're checking to see if the product doesn't have a value for `customer_product_customer`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try  'key' => 'custom_product_customer', 'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS' to find empty values

Comment: This doesn't work for me unfortunately. :(

Comment: old answer sorry.. it should be 'meta_compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'